# Idea behind Conway's lemma for proving Runge's theorem

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

> Lemma: Let $U$ and $V$ be open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ with $V \subseteq U$ and $\partial V\cap U= \phi $. If $H$ is a component of $U$ and $H \cap V \neq \phi$, then $H\subseteq V$.

I understand the proof given in Conway. However, I am unable to picture open subsets with the above property. If $V \subseteq U$, how can we have $\partial V\cap U= \phi $? The only case I can think of is the trivial one where $V$ is a component of $U$ and if $H$ is a component of $U$ with $H \cap V \neq \phi$, then $H= V$.

Specifically, taking $U= B(0,1) \cup B(0,2)$ and $V=B(0,1)$. Can anyone give me a non-trivial example where inclusion is proper?

Comment: You can take $U$ the union of three disjoint open balls and $V$ the union of two of them. This lemma says that there can be non nontrivial situation: $V$ needs to be a union of connected components of $U$.